# How can I get Page Language of web site with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm very new to lxml,html.
I want to know what language(s) it uses? (e.g. Persian-English-Arabic....)
Can I use meta tags on websites? For example---> (Meta tags, http-equiv).
How can I read that value?

Are those tags considered valid, and are they often used on websites?

Comment: You're more likely to get it from the [http headers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Response_fields) you get with the response. Maybe `content-language`?

Comment: @Holloway However when I peek into the response of this question I see no `Content-Language` at all.

Comment: There are two different questions here: 1/ *How to identify the language in a HTML web page* and 2/ *How to do that in Python*. They are different problems.

Answer (score 1):

### Reading HTML `lang` attribute

HTML documents *should* have a `lang` attribute at the root level, like this:

```
<html lang="sv">
```

(See W3C ["Declaring language in HTML"](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations.en) for more information.)

If you know that you can rely on the `lang` attribute being correctly set, use an HTML parser such as `lxml` or `html5lib` to extract the attribute.

Example using [lxml](https://lxml.de/):

```
import lxml.html

with open("foo.html", "rb") as f:
    root = lxml.html.parse(f).getroot()
    print(root.attrib.get("lang"))
```

Example using [html5lib](https://html5lib.readthedocs.io/):

```
import html5lib

with open("foo.html", "rb") as f:
    document = html5lib.parse(f)
    print(document.attrib.get("lang"))
```

### Identifying language from content

However, in many web pages, the `lang` attribute is not set or incorrectly set to some default value. In this case, you should use a package like `langdetect` to attempt to identify (read: guess) the content language using machine learning techniques.

Example using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) (to extract the body text) and [langdetect](https://github.com/Mimino666/langdetect) (for the language detection):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from langdetect import detect

with open("foo.html", "rb") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f)
    [s.decompose() for s in soup("script")]  # remove <script> elements
    body_text = soup.body.get_text()
    print(detect(body_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP header might look like this

> Content-language: es
>   Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

But it says that the document is intended for Spanish language speakers (it doesn't, however mean the document is written in Spanish; it could, for example, be written in English as part of a language course for Spanish speakers).

Or, to quote the spec:

> The Content-Language entity-header field describes the natural language(s) of the intended audience for the enclosed entity. Note that this might not be equivalent to all the languages used within the entity-body.

If the author of the website chose to make use of proper tagging, it should be on root level.

```
<html lang="es">
```

Keyword being "chose". The author is not obliged to do this.

The best way of detecting the language of a website is to simply scrape the content and throw a machine learning algorithm at it.

The simplest being NGrams, which still achieves a high accuracy (given there is enough text to draw information from).

More information can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I have a big problem.
I do not have a good acquaintance with machine learning.
I should learn faster(machine learning algorithm)?

Answer (score 0):

If lang="es" meta is not Declared in the html you can to use (langdetect, requests, html2text) Modules with the following function to convert your website html to text then **autodetect** **language** :

Let's install the Modules First :

**pip install langdetect && pip install requests && pip install html2text**

```
from langdetect import detect
import requests
import html2text

def Detect_Lang(url):
    response = requests.get(url) # Requests to get url html
    rep = response.text # html 
    txt=html2text.html2text(rep) # converting html to text
    response.close() # Close your Request
    return detect(txt) # Return language value Exp: (en, ar, pl, es) ...

linklang=Detect_Lang("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199348/how-can-i-get-page-language-of-web-site-with-python") # Run Your Function

print(linklang) # Print Language
```